# how to click button second time after 1st time click using JS

Tags: javascript, html, css, django, frontend

here my code:

```
function report(){
    setTimeout(function () {
    var mehran = new URL('http://example.com');
    window.open(mehran);
    /* alert("h") */
    }, 5000);
}
<span><button type="submit" id="reportclick"
        style="color:white; background-color:coral; border: 1 px sloid black; width:100px; margin: auto;"
        onclick="report()">Get Report</button></span>
```

I want to open open this link automatically after 5 seconds when i click on button first time.

Comment: For starters, [add an event listener](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) to your button.

Comment: Please [edit] to change your screenshot of code into a code-block (text). This helps with search engines to make your question discoverable to others, and also with accessibility to tools like screen-readers.

Answer (score -1):

As per detail provided by you, need button click to detect first time click. if first time then open specific link, otherwise link should not open after next click.

```js
function Report()
{
    //check if button has already click.   
    if(localStorage.getItem("buttonclic") != "firsttime")
    {
        setTimeout(function () {
          var openit = new URL("http://google.com");
          window.open(openit);
        }, 100);
    }
    localStorage.setItem("buttonclic","firsttime");
 
}
```

```html
<form action="#" onsubmit="Report()">
   
  <p><input type="submit" value="Submit"></p>
</form>
```

hope this helps, please comment if any query.

Comment: this solution is not working

Comment: any error showing

Comment: no i am not getting any kind error

Comment: @MehranAzam, You need to give more context / code, otherwise it's not possible to help you..

Comment: try above code again , i have made some changes

Comment: @ChenBr basically I am working on an Application. This application submit data on oracle database server. I want to open oracle report link in new tab when i submit form.

Comment: the same report link is working on another button but i want to open it when i submit form.

Comment: made changes in code on form submit , try it